# "Cannot set property of undefined", even though array has already been initialized

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create a 2D array of objects, and then set the value of one element's property.

```
var maze=new Maze(3);
maze.resetField();

function Maze(size){
    this.size=size;
    this.xPos=0;
    this.yPos=0;
    this.field=[];
    this.resetField=function(){
        this.field=[];
        this.xPos=0;
        this.yPos=0;
        var row;
        var newWord;
        var newPlace;
        for(rowCtr=0;rowCtr<this.size;rowCtr++){
            row=[];
            for(r=0;r<this.size;r++){
                newWord="rowCtr"+rowCtr+"r"+r;
                newPlace=Place(newWord);
                row[r]=newPlace;
            }
            this.field.push(row);
        }
        treasureX=1;
        treasureY=1;
        this.field[treasureY][treasureX].word="treasure";
    }

}

function Place(word){
    this.word=word;
    this.walls=[];
    this.addWall=function(route){
        this.walls.add(route);
    }
}
```

When the code reaches this line:

```
this.field[treasureY][treasureX].word="treasure";
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'word' of undefined
```

But since I've already initialized all the array elements with the nested `for` loops, shouldn't `this.field[treasureY][treasureX]` already be defined as an instance of `Place`?

Comment: So either `treasureY` or `treasureX` isn't what you think it is, or the array has no such index (arrays are zero based)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) for a new instance of `Place`.

```
newPlace = new Place(newWord);
//         ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You must replace:

```
newPlace=Place(newWord);
```

by

```
newPlace=new Place(newWord);
```

If you don't use the `new` keyword, the variable `newPlace` will be set to undefined, so all your array elements will be undefined.